# Enforce div/textbox to be displayed in one line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I force the below to be displayed in one line?
(At the moment both text-boxes are being displayed underneath each other)

```
            <form>
               <div class="loginDiv">
               Username : <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" name="username">
               Password : <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" name="password">
               </div>
           </form>

     <style type="text/css">
        .resizedTextbox {width: 50px; height: 25px}
        .loginDiv{font-size: 12px;}
    </style>
```

Comment: input tags are already inline elements, you should see both textboxes in one line only.

Comment: Are you using other css? They are currently in one line only: http://jsfiddle.net/Akzaa/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` to your CSS as shown:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .resizedTextbox {
      width: 50px;
      height: 25px;
      display:inline-block;
    }
    .loginDiv {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
</style>

    <form>
       <div class="loginDiv">
          Username : <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" name="username">
          Password : <input type="text" class="resizedTextbox" name="password">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to set either `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to the elements you want displayed inline.

Do read up on what they [actually do](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display), so you don't run into any surprises.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `display: inline-block` but I ran a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDJEV/) and it was already inline without the extra css.  Are you sure there's no other css somewhere else that's overriding that?

Comment: yes there was an input[type="text"],input[type="password"] overiding it I check from the inspect element. It is now fixed.